# Google doesn't index www-version

Tags: seo, canonical-url

Currently I am trying to get my website being index properly in google. Within the initial push, google index the website with non-www. After that I set the www-version as preferred in Webmaster Tools and also included a canonical tag on the landing page (and for each individual subpage with www.example.com/subpage).

After pushing these updates, Google indexed all other pages properly with www. The landing page was not re-indexed and is still indexed with the non-www domain. It is important that Google indexes this page, since I put new site title and meta data in it to reach my target audience.

In Webmaster the www version is marked as excluded with the message:

> Google chose another page than the user as canonical.

Is this just a matter of time or I am doing something significantly wrong? What would be the best approach for a solution here?

PS: here is the current redirect status of the non-www:

```
curl -I http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 09 May 2018 16:02:04 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.example.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I am working on making this a 301 redirect, maybe the problem is laying here.. or in my impatience.

Comment: "my impatience" - how long is it since you made these changes and implemented the redirect. A 301 and patience is certainly going to help. To be honest, there's not much else you can do. Short of updating your page and manually fetching and submitting the URL for indexing in GSC.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. It is 2 weeks ago. My concern here is if I should stick to googles decision (non-www) or to mine. I read about that you should accept googles decision. Any idea if this is true?

Comment: You should definitely make it a 301 instead of a 302. Make sure that your XML sitemap lists the correct URLs and resubmit it in Search Console. Perhaps share on social media or build a couple of new backlinks to encourage Googlebot to return to that page and recrawl it.